# Image Processing and Image Blending

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Currently I doing the fun Project "Which cricket player your face matches".I have completed 90% of the project.I am able to predict the cricket player using the user's face.But I am struct with presenting the output to the users.I want the output to be presented in the below picture type(sample output).Where first is the Image is the user image and last one cricket player.Can anyone tell combine two images as the images in the 2&4th position using python? It could better you if pride some code in python.

Sample output 1:

[image: Sample output]

sample output 2:

[image: sample output 2]

thanks in advance

Comment: This is called face morphing. Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.learnopencv.com/face-morph-using-opencv-cpp-python/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeru Luke.I  think that will be helpful